# What is the correct way to refer to Java members in text?

Tags: java

In answering questions I find myself referring to method names and online documentation often. I'm confused about how method names should be referenced in text.

For example I often type:

> One should use `String.equals()` for
>   comparing two strings for equality.

However, this is a little misleading:

1. It makes `equals()` appear to be a static member.
2. It makes `equals()` appear to not take any arguments.

In the interest of compleness, I would like to know:

**What is the correct way to refer to both static members and instance members?**

I've seen things like:

- String.equals()
- String#equals()
- myString.equals()

**Is there a way to refer to methods in an argument-agnostic manner?**

For example, in C `foo(void)` is explicitly a zero-argument function and `foo()` can be redefined later to have a different set of arguments. (?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be really be exact you could use

```
java.lang.String#equals(java.lang.Object)
```

or the shorter form

```
String#equals(Object)
```

This is similar to the notation used in javadoc and interestingly also looks similar to the link to the documentation which ends with:

```
String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)
```

**Edit:** Here is a link to the [javadoc documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#specifyingname) describing how to use references.

Comment: Is there also an argument-agnostic form?

Comment: If there is only one method of that name you can of course omit the parameter type. After all, this is a naming convention, not a hard rule.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that a link to the documentation for String's [`equals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method removes the ambiguity.

Comment: hmm, I think though that we should be able to refer accurately to members without a link to the documentation

Comment: @Matthew: Why would you want to do that?  You're on the Web.  A hyperlink is the accepted way to refer to another resource.  Link to it once, and any subsequent mentions of it should be clear.

Comment: Well, I don't really want to hyperlink to String#equals(Object) all the time. I just want to mention it. Pretend that it's not the focus of the answer, but rather just a side-method.

Answer (score 2):

Using myString.equals() makes no sense unless you state very clear, that myString is an instance of String. 
javadoc uses String#equals() so that should be readable and understandable by most developers. This would be my choice.

Comment: I'm also interested in (eliminating) the implication by String#equals() that it is a zero-argument method.

Comment: You could write "the `String#equals` method" -- leave out the parens and add the word "method" -- to indicate a non-deterministic reference to some method (perhaps one out several) named `equals` in the `String` class.

Answer (score 2):

`String.equals`.

If you wanted to give argument types `String.equals(Object)`.

Adding the parentheses (`equals()`) is a C thing. In particularly an ANSI C thing, in which a no-args function would be written as `tostring(void)` (I'm actually too young(!) to remember K&R/PCC C). C++ fixed that - so the `()` are really quite old school.

Comment: Again, this seems to imply that equals is a static member, no?

Comment: `.` is used for qualification of names in Java. This is a "slightly qualified name". In fact, it appears as a dot in stack traces.

Answer (score 1):

I generally reference the class and method name, with the expectation that the reader can use that to track down the documentation. Perhaps that's a little arrogant. I don't know.

If I'm trying to make a point about which *signature* of a method to use, I'll usually provide sample code. This is mainly because I find it easier than writing out the description long-hand.

Answer (score 1):

`myString.equals()` is perfect. It **implies** the type and makes it clear that we are talking about an instance.

You could even add:

`myString.equals(aString)`

Comment: I feel like this is the best way to give an example to beginners.

Answer (score 0):

When referring to a method, I use *"String.equals()"*. This is for human readers, and they likely to know what you are talking about from the context. In case it could become confusing, just say *"method String.equals()"*

```
One should use String.equals() for comparing two strings for equality.
```

Seriously, who would ever be confused by this sentence? So don't worry. It's just English language, there is no compiler yelling at you.